# Animate LayouParams to wrap_content

Tags: android, android-animation

I can animate the height of a view by setting LayoutParams like this

```
void animateHeight(final View view, int newHeight) {
    int currentHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(currentHeight, newHeight);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar if I want the final height to be wrap_content?

Answer (score 3):

In order to do that, you will need to emulate the way Android layouts and measures views. This is a complex process, you can see the explanation [in the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html).

An alternative approach, if is possible to change your layout, will be to use [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) and [`ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html). You can see more information about it in this [Google official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html) and also in this [training (also by Google, with source code)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0).

So, if `ConstraintLayout` works for you, you can see [this article](https://robinhood.engineering/beautiful-animations-using-android-constraintlayout-eee5b72ecae3) on how to leverage `ConstraintSet` to create clean, beautiful animations.

Hope this gets you in the right track!

Answer (score 1):

```
fun animateHeightWrapContent(view: View, show: Boolean) {
        var startHeight: Int = 0
        var endHeight: Int = 0
        if (show) {
            view.layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            startHeight = 0
            endHeight = view.measuredHeight
        } else {
            startHeight = view.measuredHeight
            endHeight = 0
        }
        val valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(startHeight, endHeight)
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener {
            val lp = view.layoutParams
            lp.height = it.animatedValue as Int
            view.layoutParams = lp
        }
        valueAnimator.duration = 250
        valueAnimator.start()
    }
```